# Mysql searching for string in text

Tags: mysql

I can't help but think my syntax is wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM  `rework` WHERE rw_pd LIKE 'FIB'
```

The SQL executes with a result of 0 rows. I KNOW there are rows with that string in that field. Anybody see any stupid mistakes?

Comment: Does it contain _only_ "F1B", or something else too (in other words; what does `LIKE '%F1B%'` give you)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the [wildcard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) if your have strings which contains FIB chained to other text:

```
SELECT * FROM  `rework` WHERE rw_pd LIKE '%FIB%'
```

Check also [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) link for various wildcards usage.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `%`, which is a wildcard.

`SELECT * FROM  rework WHERE rw_pd LIKE '%FIB%'`